# How to assert that zero or only one of N given arguments is passed

Tags: python

I have a definition like this

```
def bar(self, foo=None, bar=None, baz=None):
    pass
```

I want to make sure a maximum of one of foo, bar, baz is passed. I can do

```
if foo and bar:
    raise Ex()

if foo and baz:
    raise Ex()
....
```

But there got be something simpler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
 initialisers = [foo, bar, baz]
 if initialisers.count(None) < len(initialisers) - 1:
     raise Ex()
```

It simply counts how many `None` are present. If they're all `None` or only one isn't then fine, otherwise it raises the exception.

Comment: Thanks. Short, sweet and simple. Me like.

Comment: Glad you like it. I had the same problem recently but with 15 initialisers.

Answer (score 6):

`x!=None` returns `True` (whose numeric value is `1`!) for non-Nones, `False` (whose numeric value is 0) for Nones.  So,

```
sum(x!=None for x in (foo, bar, baz))
```

is the simplest way to count how many of those identifiers are bound to non-None values (and you can check that count against 1 just like other answers do for *their* ways of obtaining the count).  This is a very general approach in that instead of `x!=None` you could be using any strictly-bool predicate of interest; for example if you have a bunch of integers and want to know how many of them have `3` as the first digit of their decimal representation,

```
sum(str(abs(x)).startswith('3') for x in (a, b, c, d, e))
```

works fine too.

Don't be queasy about "summing bools": Python bools are sharply defined as a subclass of int with exactly two instances which have peculiar str/repr but otherwise behave exactly like the plain ints 0 and 1. There are good pragmatical reasons for this design and the ability to do arithmetic on bools is one of them, so feel free to **use** that ability!-)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
 count = sum(map(lambda x: 0 if x is None else 1, (foo, bar, baz)))
 if count > 1:
     raise Ex()
```

That turns `None` into 0 and everything into 1 and then sums everything up.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works, I just found Scott's answer more explicit and simple so accpted it.

Comment: or without lambda:
count = sum(0 if x == None else 1 for x in [foo, bar, baz])

Comment: Yeah, I'm not used to the new list thingy :)

Comment: Using the count method is probably simplest, but if you're going to use a custom generator expression, probably the cleanest would be:

count = sum(1 for x in [foo, bar, baz] if x is not None)

Answer (score 2):

I have even shorter answer, with my favorite python feature - decorators:

```
def single_keyword(func):
    def single_keyword_dec(*args, **kw):
        if len(kw) > 1:
            raise Exception("More than one initializer passed: {0}".format(kw.keys()))
        return func(*args, **kw)
    return single_keyword_dec

@single_keyword
def some_func(self, foo=None, bar=None, baz=None):
    print foo, bar, baz

some_func(object, foo=0)
some_func(object, foo=0, bar=0)
#result
0 None None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dec2.py", line 13, in <module>
    some_func(object, foo=0, bar=0)
  File "dec2.py", line 4, in single_keyword_dec
    raise Exception("More than one initializer passed: {0}".format(kw.keys()))
Exception: More than one initializer passed: ['foo', 'bar']
```

If you need distinguish between 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' and some other keywords, you could make similiar decorator which would accept list of keywords to restrict, and use it like this: `@single_keyword('foo', 'bar', 'baz')`

This way its 100% code reuse, no typing same thing over and over, and you get proper keywords in your function, not some obscure dict.

Answer (score 1):

```
if len(filter(lambda x: x != None, locals().values())) > 1:
    raise Exception()
```

Edited to address Alex's point.

Comment: This is wrong as it filters away 0s and ''s as well as Nones.

Answer (score -1):

Like this.

```
def func( self, **kw ):
    assert len(kw) == 1, "Too Many Arguments"
    assert kw.keys[0] in ( 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ), "Argument not foo, bar or baz"
```

Comment: -1 Yuk. Most **inelegant** solution. (1) `assert` will vanish if run with optimising flag (2) already need to do own arg-name checking (3) you have omitted the subsequent code for doing own default-handling e.g. `foo = kw.get('foo')`